# Remove grey header-box in AmCharts

Tags: javascript, charts, amcharts

While plotting some historical data on a chart I stumbled on this annoying grey box that I can't get rid of.

Basically I started with this example: http://www.amcharts.com/demos/date-based-data/ and did some slight modifications (removed chartScrollbar).

The chart is using type: **serial** with theme: **light**.

Still haven't found anything in the documentation http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/ that resembles this.

I've tried 'guides', 'graphs', 'chartScrollBar' but nothing seems to work.

Appreciate any help in this.

**Chart with grey header-box:**

[image: Gray box]

**AmCharts conf:**

```
        chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
            "type": "serial",
            "theme": "light",
            "marginLeft": 0,
            "marginRight": 0,
            "autoMarginOffset": 0,
            "path": "http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/",
            "dataDateFormat": "YYYY-MM-DD",
            "valueAxes": [{
                "id": "v1",
                "axisAlpha": 0,
                "position": "left"
            }],
            "balloon": {
                "borderThickness": 1,
                "shadowAlpha": 0
            },
            "graphs": [{
                "id": "g1",
                "bullet": "round",
                "bulletBorderAlpha": 1,
                "bulletColor": "#FFFFFF",
                "bulletSize": 5,
                "hideBulletsCount": 50,
                "lineThickness": 2,
                "title": "red line",
                "useLineColorForBulletBorder": true,
                "valueField": "value",
                "balloonText": "<div style='margin:5px; font-size:19px;'><span style='font-size:13px;'>[[category]]</span><br>[[value]]</div>"
            }],
            "chartScrollbar": {
                "enabled": false
            },
            "chartCursor": {
                "pan": true,
                "valueLineEnabled": true,
                "valueLineBalloonEnabled": true,
                "cursorAlpha": 0,
                "valueLineAlpha": 0.2
            },
            "categoryField": "date",
            "categoryAxis": {
                "parseDates": true,
                "dashLength": 1,
                "minorGridEnabled": true,
                "position": "bottom"
            },
            "export": {
                "enabled": false
            },
            "dataProvider": chartData
        });
```

Comment: Seems as if `enabled: false` should work. You might want to log a support ticket for that. Until then, you can use `"scrollbarHeight": 0.1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "grey box" is chart scrollbar. By default chart does not display the scrollbar. So to remove it simply remove it from your chart config altogether:

```
chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
    "type": "serial",
    "theme": "light",
    "marginLeft": 0,
    "marginRight": 0,
    "autoMarginOffset": 0,
    "path": "http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/",
    "dataDateFormat": "YYYY-MM-DD",
    "valueAxes": [{
        "id": "v1",
        "axisAlpha": 0,
        "position": "left"
    }],
    "balloon": {
        "borderThickness": 1,
        "shadowAlpha": 0
    },
    "graphs": [{
        "id": "g1",
        "bullet": "round",
        "bulletBorderAlpha": 1,
        "bulletColor": "#FFFFFF",
        "bulletSize": 5,
        "hideBulletsCount": 50,
        "lineThickness": 2,
        "title": "red line",
        "useLineColorForBulletBorder": true,
        "valueField": "value",
        "balloonText": "<div style='margin:5px; font-size:19px;'><span style='font-size:13px;'>[[category]]</span><br>[[value]]</div>"
    }],
    "chartCursor": {
        "pan": true,
        "valueLineEnabled": true,
        "valueLineBalloonEnabled": true,
        "cursorAlpha": 0,
        "valueLineAlpha": 0.2
    },
    "categoryField": "date",
    "categoryAxis": {
        "parseDates": true,
        "dashLength": 1,
        "minorGridEnabled": true,
        "position": "bottom"
    },
    "export": {
        "enabled": false
    },
    "dataProvider": chartData
});
```